# Splitting Pdf to multiple smaller Pdf - limit with the file-size

Tags: java, itext

The below code does the splitting into smaller pdf files. However, the last pdf file it create gets corrupted. If anyone is able to help with this, where I am doing wrong?

PdfReader Split_PDF_By_Size = new PdfReader("/tutorial.pdf");
Document document = new Document();

```
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream("/File1.pdf"));
        document.open();

        int number_of_pages = Split_PDF_By_Size.getNumberOfPages();
        int pageNumber = 1; /* To generate file name dynamically */
        // int Find_PDF_Size; /* To get PDF size in bytes */
        float combinedSize = 0; /* To convert this to Kilobytes and estimate new PDF size */

        for (int i = 1; i < number_of_pages; i++ ) {
            float Find_PDF_Size;

            if (combinedSize == 0 && i != 1) {
                document = new Document();
                pageNumber++;
                String FileName = "File" + pageNumber + ".pdf";
                copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(FileName));
                document.open();
            }

            copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(Split_PDF_By_Size, i));

            Find_PDF_Size = copy.getCurrentDocumentSize();

            combinedSize = (float)Find_PDF_Size / 1024;

            if (combinedSize < 250 ||  i == number_of_pages) {
                document.close();
                combinedSize = 0;
            } 
        }

        System.out.println("PDF Split By Size Completed. Number of Documents Created:" + pageNumber);
    }
    catch (Exception i)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Comment: Off, topic, I don't know why you have `combinedSize % 2 > 250`, but that will never be `true`.

Comment: In fact, that whole `if/else` is a bit strange.  Both branches have `document.close();` - the only difference is resetting a variable which is about to go out of scope anyway.

Comment: And `i == number_of_pages` is never true, since you only iterate the loop when `i < number_of_pages` , and you never increase `i` in the loop itself.

Comment: if (combinedSize  < 250 ||  i == number_of_pages) {
                document.close();
                combinedSize = 0;
            }

Sorry guys I was trying out something before pasting the wrong code, I have updated the code. Can you guys plz have a look? @DawoodibnKareem

Comment: `i` will still never be equal to `number_of_pages`.

Comment: I have removed that i == number of pages as said @Dawood ibn Kareem, I found the issue, forget to close the document.close() for the first one. But comes with another issue now the last page of the pdf is missing after splitting (PDF has 62 pages and I can find 61).

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine - with splitting large PDF into multiple smaller size pdf [Using file size limitation]

PdfReader Split_PDF_By_Size = new PdfReader("Test_page.pdf");
Document document = new Document();

```
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream("File1.pdf"));
        document.open();

        int number_of_pages = Split_PDF_By_Size.getNumberOfPages();
        int pageNumber = 1; /* To generate file name dynamically */
        // int Find_PDF_Size; /* To get PDF size in bytes */
        /* To convert this to Kilobytes and estimate new PDF size */
        float combinedSize = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_pages; i++ ) {
            float Find_PDF_Size;

            if (combinedSize == 0 && i != 1) {
                document = new Document();
                pageNumber++;
                String FileName = "File" + pageNumber + ".pdf";
                copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(FileName));
                document.open();
            }

            copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(Split_PDF_By_Size, i));

            Find_PDF_Size = copy.getCurrentDocumentSize();

            combinedSize = (float)Find_PDF_Size / 1024;

            if (combinedSize > 300) {
                document.close();
                combinedSize = 0;
            }
        }

        document.close();
        System.out.println("Number of Documents Created:" + pageNumber);
    }
    catch (Exception i)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```